# Thin icon design

Tags: inkscape, icon, interface-design

`YouTube` is using `Thin icons`, `Font Awesome 6` has a thin icon pack. I wonder whether there is any guide or resource available that talk about designing thin icons for UI. Or is it draw something and set it to stroke= 1px ? Any tips on this will be great.

Comment: I don't really see YouTube using "thin icons", but maybe it's a regional thing? They are filled as far as I can see. Anyway, I don't think that there are "rules" as such. The stroke width would depend on how big you design the icons, which final size they will have and the general design aesthetic of the project.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen various guides on Fluent Design, Material Design etc. I thought perhaps there is one for Thin Design too. 32px canvas might be a good place to start with 2px margin

Comment: There is probably a good guide, I just don't know any. I do think 32 px sounds awfully small. Not much room for details with 1px strokes being the minimum. Depends of course on what the icons will be used for. Find a set of icons you like and see how they are made.